# How to implement Counting Sort on array of Student ID associate with Score

Tags: c, sorting, pseudocode

I have an array of student ID with their respective score.
The student ID is sorted. I tried to sort score and get the final sorted position. How to move the student ID to its final position as well?
The output i get after sort is

```
struct SResult sample[] = {
    {"A1234", 10},
    {"A1239", 5},
    {"A1394", 7},
    {"A1434", 3},
    {"A1454", 5},
    {"A2884", 7},
    {"A3235", 7},
    {"A4334", 9},
    {"A4884", 2},
    {"A6934", 5},
    {"A7265", 7},
    {"A9559", 3}
};
```

I have tried to implement the counting sort algorithm and the sorted output is

```
[, 3]
[   , 1]
[
, 5]
[, 0]
[, 0]
[, 0]
[, 0]
[, 0]
[, 0]
[, 0]
[, 0]
[, 0]

#define MAX_SCORE 1000


void counting_sort(struct SResult scoreArr[], int N, int final[]) {
    int freq[MAX_SCORE + 1] = {0}, cfreq[MAX_SCORE + 1] = {0};
    int i, curScore;

    //1. Compute Frequency
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++){
        freq[ scoreArr[i].score ] ++;
    }

    //2. Compute Cumulative Frequency
    cfreq[0] = freq[0];
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++){
        cfreq[i] = cfreq[i - 1] + freq[i];
    }

    //3. Produce Final Position
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        curScore = scoreArr[i].score;
        final[ cfreq[ curScore ] - 1 ] = i;
        cfreq[curScore]--;
    }
}
```

Comment: `final` should be an array of `SResult`.

Comment: Have you written the posted code? Or has it been given to you and now your task is to actually sort the array `sample` using the values held in `final` ?